# pygtk i18n problem---pygtk builtin widgets

Tags: pygtk

I am using pygtk and glade to build apps and I have a problem here. I used some gtk-builtin widgets in my app. And I don't know how to localize some label texts. For example

```
           button =  gtk.BUTTON_YES_NO
           xxxDialog(data, button,text1, text2, xyz)
```

this would produce a dialog box with two buttons on it, one reads "Yes" and the other "NO". THe question is what sould I do to localize Yes and No to my native language. I do know how to localize texts in python codes(just preappend texts with _() and create a po/mo file), but I don't know how to deal with gtk-builtin widgets. Could you guys please help me with it? Any guidance would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at files `/usr/share/locale-langpack/*/LC_MESSAGES/gtk20.mo` which are gtk translation files. You can decompile them (to .po text file) using gettext command.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do anything, built-in widgets are automatically localized.